Sorting algorithm that sorts every N elements of an array
I am looking for an algorithm that sorts every N element of an array.
For example  lets says The array is 7 8 6 4 5 1 4 3 5 and N is 3.
I want the sorted array to be 6 7 8 1 4 5 3 4 5
Please note that the array size is a multiple of N.
I wrote the below algorithm for N==3 but not sure how to handle for higher value of N
for ( ll i=0;i<N;i+=3) 
{
    if (A1[i]> A1[i+1])
    {
        swap(A1[i+1],A1[i]);
    }
    if(A1[i+1] > A1[i+2])
    {
        swap(A1[i+2],A1[i+1]);
    }
}


Use std::sort array.size()/N times in a loop (each iteration on the next N values).

What is ll in your code?

it is long long

Roughly sort(begin(A)+i*N),begin(A)+(i+1)*N) with i varying from 0 to array.size()/N  (beware of the last segment that can be too short).

In Ruby: arr.each_slice(n).flat_map(&:sort).

long long is long long. Don't use nonsensical typedefs, they don't help, they bite.

Obligatory solution using C++20 ranges:
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {7,8,6,4,5,1,4,3,5};
    int n = 3;

    for (auto &&segment : arr | std::views::chunk(n))
        std::ranges::sort(segment);

    for (int x : arr)
        std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}

But since you're probably asked to implement this manually: Make a sorting function (using whatever algorithm you want) that just sorts an entire array. It will probably accept a pointer and a length as parameters (or two pointers). You can then apply it to individual subarrays in a loop.

That's fancy! I need to find some time to look at ranges and such.

I would argue that traditional loops must retire. <ranges> brings safety,  readability and laziness to code.

Unfortunately ranges do not bring pizza and beer. But they do give you more time to run out and get pizza and beer.
